# Docker container that pulls from private gilab repository

Tags: node.js, docker

I'm building a Docker container for my Node.js + Vue application.

Since I have a global css library in another repository I have added this line in my package.json file:

```
"lib-css": "git+ssh://git@git.lib.com:9922/username/lib-css.git#development",
```

That way when I run `npm install` I install also my CSS library. The problem is that on my local env it asks for my password and I can insert it, but in the Docker build the process fails with the following error:

```
Step 7/10 : RUN npm install
 ---> Running in db10ca83586d
npm WARN deprecated babel-preset-es2015@6.24.1:   Thanks for using Babel: we recommend using babel-preset-env now: please read babeljs.io/env to update!
npm ERR! Error while executing:
npm ERR! /usr/bin/git ls-remote -h -t ssh://git@git.lib.com:9922/username/lib-css.git
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Host key verification failed.
npm ERR! fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please make sure you have the correct access rights
npm ERR! and the repository exists.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! exited with error code: 128

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2017-12-11T08_49_11_152Z-debug.log
```

This is my current `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM node:carbon

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

RUN mkdir -p /root/.ssh
COPY .secrets /root/.ssh/id_rsa
RUN chmod 700 /root/.ssh && chmod 600 /root/.ssh/*

# Install app dependencies
# A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied
# where available (npm@5+)
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install
# If you are building your code for production
# RUN npm install --only=production

# Bundle app source
COPY . .

EXPOSE 8081
CMD [ "npm", "run dev" ]
~
```

My `.secrets` file contains my private key associated to the repository.

How can I make this works?

Comment: Can you use personal access tokens? https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line/

Comment: And how can I output them in the Dockerfile?

Comment: Did you find any solution, please let me know